# Child and parent ripple triggered

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify to design a 'card' component.

I have a parent div with a child button. Now, when I click the button, the ripple effect on the div is triggered.

How can I fix this?

```
<template>

  <div>

    <v-card v-ripple="true">
      <h3>
        <v-card-title>{{ title }}</v-card-title>
      </h3>

      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex grow>
          <v-card-text>
            {{ plaats }}
            <br />
            {{ sub_title }}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex shrink>
          <v-card-actions>

            <v-btn small color="blue" fab>
              <v-icon medium color="white">mdi-calendar</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn small color="green" fab>
              <v-icon medium color="white">mdi-calendar-check</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn small color="red" fab>
              <v-icon medium color="white">mdi-calendar-remove</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

          </v-card-actions>
        </v-flex>

      </v-layout>
    </v-card>

  </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was indeed `Event.stopPropagation` but I had to add it to the mousedown action.
So `@mousedown.stop` and then add your function with `@click.stop="null"` as @Frank mentioned before.

Comment: Also consider adding `@touchstart.stop` to `Event.stopPropagation` on touch devices, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** `@mousedown` event will not fire on mobile, thus we also need to 
add `@touchstart`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/traxo/pen/eXmrRw)

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile :ripple="true" @click="">

    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-btn 
          @click.stop="" 
          @mousedown.stop="" 
          @touchstart.stop=""
      >Click</v-btn>
    </v-list-tile-action>

    <v-list-tile-content class="pl-5">
      Click tile
    </v-list-tile-content>

  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Event.stopPropagation`. Add `@click.stop="null"` to your button(s). Of course you can/should replace `null` with your own method.

Comment: That doesn't work for the ripple effect though. Already tried that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you add a working example? I tried recreating your issue but no success.

Answer (score -2):

if your vuetify css is separate, not in your app.js,
the solution that worked for me is to put the app.js script outside the body, when it is inside the js loads first than the vuetify css.

```html
<!-- ripple error occurs randomly -->
  <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/vLib.js') }}" defer></script> 
</body>


<!-- Should be outside the body -->
</body>
  <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/vLib.js') }}" defer></script>
```