# vuetify: Stop parent animation on click

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a card which have 2 buttons and I want to have difference function when clicking on:

1. Card
2. Button `Yes`
3. Button `No`

I layout the card this way

```
<v-card
  @click.self="$emit('card:clicked')"
>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer/>
      <v-btn
        @click.stop="$emit('btn:yes')"
      >
        Yes
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        @click.stop="$emit('btn:no')"
      >
        No
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

With modifier `stop` I can emit `btn:yes` or `btn:no` event without emit event `card:clicked` on card, but the clicked animation on card still show and is very confusing.

My question is how I can stop the animation happen like stopping the event `card:clicked` when I click on the button instead of the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more search I find out the `animation` call `ripple` with vuetify.

With the right words I am able to find the answer at [Child and parent ripple triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536822/child-and-parent-ripple-triggered)

And I can solve my issue by adding `@mousedown.stop` like below

```
<v-card
  @click.self="$emit('card:clicked')"
>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer/>
      <v-btn
        @click.stop="$emit('btn:yes')"
        @mousedown.stop
      >
        Yes
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        @click.stop="$emit('btn:no')"
        @mousedown.stop
      >
        No
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```